# 'contains' for numpy library?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Something like this:

This works:

```
df.C = np.where((df.C.values == 'yes')), 'no', df.C.values)
```

But if the word is part of the row and no tht e whole row something like 'contains' from pandas would be needed.

```
df.C = np.where((df.C.values.contains('ye')), 'no', df.C.values)
```

but this doesn't work.

I would like to use numpy because of the speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df.C = np.where(df.C.str.contains('ye').values, 'no', df.C.values)
```

If performance is important:

```
df.C = np.where(['ye' in x for x in df.C], 'no', df.C.values)

df.loc[['ye' in x for x in df.C], 'C'] = 'no'
```

**Performance**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C':['aa ss ye','a s d','fff', 'yeye']})

#[40000 rows x 1 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)
print (df)

In [13]: %timeit df.C = np.where(df.C.str.contains('ye').values, 'no', df.C.values)
21.6 ms ± 294 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [14]: %timeit df.C = np.where(['ye' in x for x in df.C], 'no', df.C.values)
3.29 ms ± 49.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [15]: %timeit df.loc[['ye' in x for x in df.C], 'C'] = 'no'
5.26 ms ± 105 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

String operation are slow in pandas, so fastest is use list comprehension with `in`. Timings in real data should be different, because depends of number of matched values and length of `DataFrame`.

Comment: And think that I used `df.C.values.str.` and didn't work. lol it needed to rmove `values`. Thanks. Can you explain what values does? I saw that it keeps only the non column part.Is this correct? and how contains works in numpy?

Comment: @user10389994 - contains not working in numpy, because not implemented. `.values` convert pandas Series to numpy array.

Comment: Your first line of code has `np.where` and `contains`. How is this happening?

Comment: @user10389994 - pandas is bult in numpy arrays, so is possible assign numpy array directly to pandas structures, here `Series`.